# Convert array of links into links - React

Tags: html, reactjs, xml, hyperlink

Im new to React. Im trying to convert an array contains links into something that will show the links in order in the website.

something like this:

```
external_references = ["https://google.com", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki"]
```

into something to show up in the server like this:

```
external_references:
https://google.com(link)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki(link)
```

I tried to do the following code I found but it failed to work:

```
<span className="externalRefs">External_references: <br></br> {external_references.forEach(link => {
                                return new DOMParser().parseFromString(link, "text/xml");
                            })}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

just

```
{external_references.map((reference, i) => {
  return(
  <div key ={i}>
   <a href ={reference}>{reference}</a>
  </div>
);
})}
```

Comment: I tried it, it is telling failing to compile, telling me '}' expected around the map(reference, i) => {}

Comment: Like I commented below, tt complied, but didn't show anything at the website at all including some stuff I added before that. Altought, if Im removing this code the other stuff showing.

Comment: Can You prepare sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

you can try the map function:

```
<p>external_references:</p>
{external_references.map(link=>{
     return <div key={link}>
               <a href={link}>{link}</a>
            </div>
     }
}
```

I recomend you as a good practice using the link as a key, since each of them should be different.

Comment: It complied, but didn't show anything at the website at all including some stuff I added before that. Altought, if Im removing your code the other stuff showing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Array.map` function.

```js
 <span className="externalRefs">External_references: <br></br> 
  {
   external_references.map(link, i) => {
    <div key ={i}>
     <a href ={link}>{link}</a>
    </div>
   }
  }
</span>
```

Comment: I tried it, it is telling failing to compile, telling me '}' expected around the map(link, i) => {}

Comment: Sorry, I missed the }. I have edited the answer.